# How do you infer type base on javascript value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this react hook which returns filter based on type props user gave.

```
interface Props {
    type: 'product' | 'content';
}

function useFilterSelector(props: Props) {
    const { t } = useClientTranslation();

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const [filterSelector] = useState(() => {
        switch (props.type) {
            case 'product':
                return new ProductFilter(t, queryClient);
            case 'content':
                return new ContentFilter(t, queryClient);
        }
    });

    return { filterSelector };
}
```

This hook works fine but the problem is that I can't get strict type inference
For example If developer provides "product" for an arguments

```
  const { filterSelector } = useFilterSelector({ type : "product"})
```

The infered type should be

```
type = ProductFilter
```

but i get

```
type = ProductFilter | ContentFilter
```

I tried this

```
function useFilterSelector(props: Props) {
    const { t } = useClientTranslation();

    type FilterType = (typeof props)['type'];
    type FilterSelector = FilterType extends 'product'
        ? ProductFilter
        : FilterType extends 'content'
        ? ContentFilter
        : unknown;

    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const [filterSelector] = useState<FilterSelector>(() => {
        switch (props.type) {
            case 'product':
                return new ProductFilter(t, queryClient);
            case 'content':
                return new ContentFilter(t, queryClient);
        }
    });

    return { filterSelector };
}
```

but the type is inferred as unknown

how do i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of conditional return type based on type of `props.type`

```
interface Props {
    type: 'product' | 'content';
}

interface ProductFilter {
  a: string;
}
interface ContentFilter {
  b: number;
}

interface FilterSelector<T extends Props> {
  filterSelector: T['type'] extends 'product' ? ProductFilter : ContentFilter
}

function useFilterSelector<T extends Props>(props: T): FilterSelector<T> {
  return { filterSelector: {} as any }
}

const pF = useFilterSelector({ type: 'product' })
pF.filterSelector.a
//               ^? (property) ProductFilter.a: string
const cF = useFilterSelector({ type: 'content' })
cF.filterSelector.b
//               ^? (property) ContentFilter.b: number
```

[Playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mqY2Ym)

Answer (score 0):

How about type assertion so that typescript will use the type instead of unknown?

```
switch (props.type) {
      case 'product':
        return new ProductFilter(t, queryClient) as FilterSelector;
      case 'content':
        return new ContentFilter(t, queryClient) as FilterSelector;
    }
```